# Jenkins in Docker - how to install docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

So I want to start using Jenkins to build my app and then test it and push my image to local repo.
Because I have 2 images to push I would like to use docker-compose, but docker-compose is missing.

I installed Jenkins through Portainer, and I'm using the jenkins/jenkins:lts image.

Is there a way to install docker-compose into the container without having to create my own Dockerfile for it?

My Jenkins pipeline so far is:

```
node {
    stage('Clone repository') {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
            branches: [[name: '*/master' ]],
            extensions: scm.extensions,
            userRemoteConfigs: [[
                url: 'repo-link',
                credentialsId: 'credentials'
            ]]
        ])
    }

    stage('Build image') {
         sh 'cd src/ && docker-compose build'
    }

    stage('Push image') {
         sh 'docker-compose push'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use plain docker to build and push images?

Comment: I have multiple images to build and I have always done it with docker-compose. Now i tried it with plain docker but i cannot build it, because I have dependency on project outside of the project i want to build.

I have a C# sln file in the /src folde
and then have Backend/ FrontEnd/ and Common/ folder. And have dependencies on the Common (.Net standart) folder, and docker doesn't allow me to copy from outside the Backend/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either install docker-compose during image build time (via Dockerfile):

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins  
USER root  
RUN curl -L \  
  "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.3/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" \  
  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \  
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  
USER jenkins
```

Or you can install docker-compose after the Jenkins container is already running via the same CURL command:

```
$ sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.3/run.sh -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```